# Kentico - Customizing subscriber fields - email Marketing

Tags: email, kentico, subscriber

I have a NewsletterSubscription Webpart on my website (Kentico 9). The fields used in this web part are the default ones. I would like to customize those by adding a required checkbox. So that people who want to subscribe have to check this checkbox.

I saw on Kentico Documentation (https://docs.kentico.com/k82/on-line-marketing-features/email-marketing/working-with-email-campaigns/managing-email-marketing-subscribers) that I can make fields changes in the Modules application.

My question is : if I made a change in the Newsletter - subscriber class (in module application) by adding this required checkbox, would it affect in any way the current subscribers of my newsletters ?

Answer (score 0):

All subscribers from that specific class will have a new field with default value as you want. If you don't define default value it will be NULL. https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/editing-system-tables

Be sure to take a backup of the database first!

Comment: Thank you for your answer !